# Cassandra batch operation support with CrudRepository

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I understand cassandra does not support transaction management, but it does support batch operations which can be used like transactions (either all will success or none).

Similarly spring-data for cassandra provides CassandraTemplate which provides batchOps to support this batch feature.

I am wondering if something similar is available to be used with CrudRepository (a high level api which internally uses CassandraTemplate).

Answer (score 0):

Batches are really used for very [limited sets of use cases](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html) - please check documentation.  It could be better to devise some other way to achieve the same goal, but this really depends on what you want to do - what operations to execute, table schemas, etc.

Comment: Thanks Alex. As it is mentioned in the documents that batches should be used when we want multiple operations to be atomic and performance will not suffer if the operations are for single partition. In our case we have multiple tables and all of them have same partition key but different cluster keys and in case of add/delete operation we want to add/delete all or none. This we achieved through cassandra template batch ops. But we are looking for achieving same through CrudRepository.